# SQL: If-condition when result does not exist?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql

The following sql snippet below is a subselect of a parent sql.

Is there a way to say, "If customer doesn't exist I want to run a different sql"?

```
select orderdate, 
    (select contactname from customers where customerID = 'ALFKI' or select 'No Customer') as contactname

from orders
```

I know this can be solved with a join but mainly interested of the possibility?

Comment: Please post what you want to run if the customer doesn't exist.

Comment: Please update your question to include what you mean by "Can this be done inline within a parent sql as a subselect?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing that you're trying to do here is called LEFT JOIN with ISNULL:

```
select OrderDate, isnull(c.FullName, 'No customer') CustomerName
from Orders o
left join Customers c on o.CustomerId = c.CustomerId
```

Answer (score 1):

example

```
IF NOT EXISTS (select * from customers where customerID = 'ALFKI')
BEGIN
    SELECT '1'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT '2'
END
```

Comment: Can this be done inline within a parent sql as a subselect?

Answer (score 1):

Please disregard this question. I should have been weary asking because the question sounded even confusing for me.

Turns out I was in the wrong place when the answer was elsewhere. The answer was solved with precedence parenthesis just like that. Sorry for the confusion.

rod.